# Cant figure out segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, string, if-statement, char

I am having trouble trying to figure out where my segmentation faults are coming from. I have narrowed it down to the function and snippet of code but I'm stumped. Mind taking a look at it?

P.S. I ask that you guys dont be too harsh on the negative votes. I am a student and im teaching myself plain c as I go. Not to mention im manipulating strings which is a pain in c so I understand my code looks like crap. But give me a break. That's why I'm here to learn.

Anyway let me know what else you need and thanks in advance.

Here is the console output.

> ```
>    rpf0024@cse02:~/cse2610$ gcc -std=gnu99 main.c
>    rpf0024@cse02:~/cse2610$ ./a.out
>
>    # A demonstration of some simple MIPS instructions
>    Loop: sll $t1, $s3,
>    add $t1, $t1, $s6
>    lw $t0, 0($t1)
>    bne $t0, $s5, Exit
>    addi $s3, $s3, 1
>    j Loop
>    Exit:
>
>    Line: 0 #
>    Line: 1
>    Line: 2 Loop
>    Line: 3 add
>    Line: 4 lw
>    Line: 5 bne
>    Line: 6 addi
>    Line: 7 j
>    Line: 8 Exit
>    WompWompWompSplitting string:
>
>    add
>    $t1
>    $t1
>    $s6
>    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
>    rpf0024@cse02:~/cse2610$
> ```

Assem.c - I have verified the segmentation faults are somewhere within my batch of "if" statements. I deleted that whole block of code and my program ran just fine.

```
int checkRformat(char *LineArray, struct assem item)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *str;
    char *temp;
    item.opcode = NULL;
    item.shamt = NULL;
    item.funct = NULL;
    item.rs = NULL;
    item.rt = NULL;
    item.rd = NULL;
    
    printf("Splitting string:\n");
    temp = strdup(LineArray);
    str = strtok(temp, " ,.-#\n\t");
    //this helper function gets called by another.It primarily serves to convert the MIPS code
    //instructions or labels into their binary values. These global variables will then concatenated
    // and be printed onto a .txt file. 
    while(str != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", str);
        str = strtok(NULL, " ,.-#\n\t");

        if(strcmp(str, "add"))
        {
            item.opcode = "000000";
            item.shamt = "00000";
            item.funct = "10100";
        }
        else if(strcmp(str, "$t0"))
        {
            if(strcmp(item.rs, NULL)){item.rs = "01000";}
            else if(item.rt, NULL){item.rt = "01000";}
            else if(item.rd,NULL){item.rd = "01000";}
        }
        else if(strcmp(str, "$t1"))
        {
            if(strcmp(item.rs,NULL)){item.rs = "01001";}
            else if(item.rt,NULL){item.rt = "01001";}
            else if(item.rd,NULL){item.rd = "01001";}
        }
        else if(strcmp(str, "$s6"))
        {
            if(strcmp(item.rs,NULL)){item.rs = "11110";}
            else if(item.rt,NULL){item.rt = "11110";}
            else if(item.rd,NULL){item.rd = "11110";}
        }
    }
}
```

assem.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct assem
{
        char myString[101];                     //buffer
        char *myLines[20];                      //this will store the lines from a text file..up to 20 lines
        char *myLines2[20];
        char *myWord[20];                       //this stores the 1st words individually.
        char *opcode;
        char *rs;
        char *rt;
        char *rd;
        char *shamt;
        char *funct;
        char counter;                           //counter for number of lines
                                                //printing stuff...prints file directly from whats STORED IN THE ARRAY
};

int readFile(FILE *FileToBeRead, struct assem *item);                                   //takes in the file that needs to be read and splits it into lines
int firstCheck(struct assem item);
int secondCheck(struct assem item);
int checkRformat(char *LineArray, struct assem item);
int checkFormat1(char *LineArray,struct assem item, int offset);
int checkFormat2(char *LineArray, struct assem item, int offset);
int checkFormat3(char *LineArray, struct assem item, int offset);
int checkFormat4(char *LineArray, struct assem item, int offset);
int checkFormat5(char *LineArray, struct assem item, int offset);
int checkFormat6(char *LineArray, struct assem item);
int checkFormat7(char *LineArray, struct assem item);
int checkLabel1(char *Array, struct assem item);
int checkLabel2(char *Array, struct assem item);
int checkLabel3(char *Array, struct assem item);
//int checkSyntax1(char *LineArray, struct assem item);
void removeSpaces(char* str_trimmed, const char* str_untrimmed, struct assem *item);    //HELPER FUNCTIONS TO REMOVE SPACES
void ReadWords(struct assem *item);                                                     //stores the first word of each line in an array for evaluation
void printFile(struct assem item);                                                      //prints some stuff
void printWords(struct assem item);                                                     //checks the first character if its instruction, label, or comment
```

Comment: Have you tried using gdb to see which line is throwing a segfault?

Comment: No i have not. TBH i didnt know about that command. gdb main.c? Thats it?

Comment: @Bamar...you're referring to my lines being staggered. How would that cause a seg fault?

Comment: He's referring to the fact that you should do a better job of formatting your code so that people here can actually read it...

Comment: To use `gdb` : 1. Compile with debug symbols enabled (`-g` option in `gcc`. 2. Run `gdb main`. 3. Enter the `run` command in `gdb`

Comment: How is checkRFormat supposed to accomplish anything? It parses text passed to it, and puts values into a local copy of a structure, and doesn't return anything.

Comment: @TiggityTank That was meant to be the edit reason, not a comment.

Comment: @Lee Daniel...this is just a helper function for another function. It computes whatever line or array I throw at it since I will have to analyze high volume of them. this function will make it easier for what i am working with. I just started working on this function a few minutes ago...it wont return anything...ill eventually edit and make the function void

Comment: @Bamar thank you. fixing the indentations did not solve the issue tho :\

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help. GDB command is something new Ill try from now on.

Comment: My point is that it can't possibly "help" anything. It has no return value and no side effects. It just writes into local stack. Perhaps you meant to pass the structure via pointer?

Comment: understood. It is true that I can copy and past this into another function and itll work just find..BUT i am comparing over 20 different literals that can trigger this checkRformat function or checkAformat function and another that i havent written...so rather free handing this code 20 times, id rather just call it from another...that way its easier to distinguish and answer questions like:
how is  "and" & "addiu" being checked..T
that was my logic in the process

Comment: wait i think i see what youre talking about hahahah

Comment: Since im modifying global variables, I should be using "*item" in my function parameter instead of "item".
so instead of say "item.opcode" i should be doing "item->opcode"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break out of the loop if `strtok()` returns `NULL`. You're not checking that until you get back to the `while` test at the top of the loop. But that's too late, because the code after `strtok()` tries to use `str`.

```
str = strtok(NULL, " ,.-#\n\t");
if (!str) {
    break;
}
```

Comment: Taking a look at this now. Thank you